# How do I check if a user has certain role and therefore allow some actions?

Tags: php, symfony, security-context

I need to check if logged in user has certain roles on the system so I allow or not some actions. I'm using JMSSecurityExtraBundle and I check the docs for [Expression Based Authorization](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions#reference) but I'm doing something wrong since code is not working. Take a look to this code:

```
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Security\Authorization\Expression\Expression;

if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted(array(new Expression('hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")')))) {
    echo "Enter";
} else {
    echo "Do not enter";
}
```

But any time I logged in, even as ADMIN which have all the rights and has ROLE_ADMIN, the only text I'm seeing is "Do not enter" which is totally wrong. In the example code as explain in [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions#programmatic-usage) the author use a `$securityContext` var but where it comes from? Where this var is defined? I assume that it will point to [SecurityContext](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html) but I'm not so sure so, where is the problem on my code? How do I check if user has certain role and therefore allow it to execute some code or not?

Comment: why don't you simply use `->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')`?

Comment: How is that? Can you please write a small piece of code to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any usage of annotation expressions if you just want to check user's roles in controller, this is sufficient:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    echo "Enter";
} else {
    echo "Do not enter";
}
```

One quick search on google would have returned you documentation section about that right away: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control

Answer (score 1):

> I allow or not some actions.

If you mean regular actions in Controllers, then handy shortcut is to use @Security annotation from `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle`.

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

But, this is not really way how you should develop roled based actions in Symfony 2. You can define it in [access_control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#understanding-how-access-control-works).

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: That's another way but if I've 500 controllers then I'll have 500 lines on the `security.yml` and is not the idea, I prefer to relay this on annotations. In the other side I'll check the ROLE for other conditional not for the complete function, anyway thanks